# Applescript to replace values in a csv file

Tags: csv, replace, applescript

I try to replace values in a csv file with AppleScript and shellscript, it works with numerical values, but not for a string-variable. If I entered a string directly to shellscript it works to. Problems with the sytax, or what could be the cause? Or is there a more elegant method to replace values in a csv file?

sysvars.csv:
15K1;xx
15K2;yy

AppleScript:
set sysvars to "Users/eduard/Desktop/sysvars.csv"
set sysvars_temp to "Users/eduard/Desktop/sysvars_temp.csv"
set Test1 to "99"
set Test2 to "Hello"

--it works

```
do shell script "awk -F\";\" '/15FK1/ {$2=" & Test1 & "} 1' OFS=\";\" " & sysvars & " >" & sysvars_temp
```

--it does not work

```
do shell script "awk -F\";\" '/15FK1/ {$2=" & Test2 & "} 1' OFS=\";\" " & sysvars & " >" & sysvars_temp
```

--it works

```
do shell script "awk -F\";\" '/15FK2/ {$2=\"Hello\"} 1' OFS=\";\" " & sysvars & " >" & sysvars_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
do shell script "awk -F\";\" '/15FK1/ {$2=\"" & Test2 & "\"} 1' OFS=\";\" " & sysvars & " >" & sysvars_temp
```